# Importing matrix csv data into R - how to convert into dataframe

Tags: r, csv, matrix, dataframe

I have a set of csv data that is saved in matrix format [attached image is an example of the matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kTIN6.png)
I would like to load the data into R and have it stored as a data frame with x$Year,x$Death,x$ASMR. How would I be able to do that?

Thanks!

CS

Comment: Hi, its probably worth having a read of some introductory material - several good sites at the link : https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info

Answer (score 2):

I think you're just looking for `read.csv()` and then change the `colnames`.  I am assuming your file is separated by commas.

```
x <- read.csv('matrix.csv', sep=',', header=T)
colnames(x) <- c('Year', 'Death', 'ASMR')
```